# HTML Random space on new line

Tags: html, css, whitespace, line-breaks

I've been working pretty comfortably with web technologies for about a year now, but I have no clue what is causing this weird behavior.

I am creating a photo sharing app. Each photo has its own page, with the time the photo was posted in the top-left corner, and the name of the poster followed, on a new line, by a caption, in the bottom-right corner. My code is below:

```
<div class="postInfo">Name goes here<br/>This is a caption</div>
```

Here are my styles:

```
.postInfo {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

When I run the page, The poster name and caption show up exactly as expected, but for some reason the caption has a space before it. I've tried every alternative, including this:

```
<p style="padding:0;margin:0">Name goes here</p>
<p style="padding:0;margin:0">This is a caption</p>
```

And there is always a space before the caption. I am completely perplexed. Does anyone have any clue what could be causing this?

Comment: What browser do you get this in?

Comment: chrome. firefox gives me the same thing

Comment: Seems [fine](http://jsfiddle.net/nW249/)

Comment: @ManofSnow There must be something I'm not seeing about my stuff in particular.

Comment: @jchitel Please post a **screenshot**

Comment: I'm am idiot. It was inheriting a `text-align:center` from an ancestor

Answer (score 0):

The element was inheriting a `text-align:center` from an ancestor. It was hard to tell what was happening because there were only two lines, so I had no idea where that space was coming from. Turns out it wasn't a space at all.